# Arrow function notation vs cartesian product notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If a function is an operation, and an operation is a binary relation, and a binary relation is an ordered pair, and an ordered pair is defined by the cartesian product (which is the set of all the ordered pairs); then the arrow notation of a function $f : A \to B$ could be represented by a relation of a subset $A \times B$, where the relation does not takes values such as $[(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 9), \ldots]$ because a function is defined as having only one output for every input?

Comment: Not very clear... see [Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Formal_definition)

Comment: But yes, a *function* is a *relation* (subset of the *cartesian product*) that satisfies the additional property of being "functional",